# Multiple List duplication removal in for loops

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a function that has to check for duplication in two lists simultaneously. One list has x values and another has y values for a cartesian system. A single coordinate can't be repeated. Currently my code looks like this:

```
    for q in range(0, len(prows)-1, 1):
            for w in range(0, len(prows)-1, 1):
                if prows[q] == prows[w] and pcols[q] == prows[w]:
                    prows.remove(prows[w])
                    pcols.remove(pcols[w])
```

Where prows are y values and pcols are x values. This works, the problem is that my first for loop only updates the length of prows after the second for loop has cycled through all its values. Because of this I get an indexing error, the first for loop still has the original length prows while the second for loop has the newer length with the removed duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xlist = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5]
ylist = [11,33,55,77,99,55]   # (5,55) dupe'd

coords = list(zip(xlist,ylist)) # list of unique coords

print(coords) # still has dupes

result = []       # empty result list, no dupes allowed
setCoords = set() # remember which coords we already put into result
for c in coords:  # go through original coords, one at a time
    if c in setCoords:  # we already added this, skip it
        continue
    setCoords.add(c)    # add to set for comparison
    result.append(c)    # add to result

print(result) # no dupes, still in order of list
```

Output:

```
[(1, 11), (3, 33), (5, 55), (7, 77), (9, 99), (5, 55)] # coords, with dupes
[(1, 11), (3, 33), (5, 55), (7, 77), (9, 99)]          # result, no dupes
```

you can also revert back to xlist and ylist doing:

```
x2 , y2 = [list(tups) for tups in zip(*result)]

print(x2)
print(y2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] 
[11, 33, 55, 77, 99]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that `dict`s preserve the insertion order of their keys (which [will become part of the specification](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) in Python 3.7 but is already true in 3.6) this can be done in one short line:

```
# create some data       
>>> import random
>>> a = [random.randint(0, 3) for _ in range(20)]
>>> b = [random.randint(0, 3) for _ in range(20)]
>>> 
>>> a
[0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]
>>> b
[1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3]
>>> 
# this one line is all we need
>>> au, bu = zip(*dict.fromkeys(zip(a, b)))
>>> 
# admire
>>> au
(0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3)
>>> bu
(1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3)
```

Note that contrary to what one might expect this doesn't work with sets---one really has to use a dict (with dummy values).